# How to go back to previous ViewController in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I make an app in VisualStudio Xamarin (**not Xamarin.Forms**) with two view controller. First view controller is list of items, second contain item's detail info. When user tap item in list, second view opens with code

```
DetailViewController detailController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("DetailViewController") as DetailViewController;
detailController._idx = idx;
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(detailController, true);
```

But I don't know how to go back to first ViewController programmatically - for example there are button "Go Back" on DetailViewController
I try to use this code:

```
backButton.TouchUpInside += (s,e) => {
  this.NavigationController.DismissViewController(true, null)
};
```

But it doesn't give any result.
Can anybody help me with this?

**UPDATED**

I changed code to:

```
backButton.TouchUpInside += (s,e) => {
  this.NavigationController.DismissViewController(true, async () => { await DismissViewControllerAsync(true); });
  ListViewController listController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ListViewController ") as ListViewController;
  this.NavigationController.PresentViewController(listController, true, null);
}
```

This work for "Go back", but when I try to choose same or another item in list and open new DetailViewController, it throw exception "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on

```
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(detailController, true);
```

(In details - I run app, ListViewController opens, I choose item1, DetailViewController opens, I tap BackButton, ListViewController opens, I chhose any item, Exception)

Comment: You updated your code and now you dismiss your viewcontroller and then you move to the next viewcontroller - Problem is, you dont have anything to navigate ack to and you get a null exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got `Push,Pop` and `Present,Dismiss` mixed up.

When the viewcontroller is put inside Navigation, you should use push and pop to control the stack.

Modify your code :

```
backButton.TouchUpInside += (s,e) => {
  this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true); 
}
```

Refer to

[Presenting a View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html)

[UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: Thank you. But does PopViewController() destroy ViewController or I have to do it manually after I came back to previous ViewController?

Comment: It will destroy after pop completes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a "back" butten to apear automatically then you need to start with a navigation controller, and from there open a viewcontroller...

See more at this link:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS_multiscreen/hello,_iOS_multiscreen_quickstart/

otherwise you need to make a butten and simply just use the samee method as before!

Ask if you don't understand it!

Comment: There are no anything about go back function in post you recommended. Only go to new ViewController

Comment: Check the Link, and search for "back" you will get something. If you have Seque between a navigation controller and a view controller a "backButten" will apear in the top when you go from one controller to another.

Comment: I have Seque only between Navigation Controller and ListViewController. That's why I call DetaIViewController programmatically.

Comment: well i see you use Presentviewcontroller - i just looked at xamarins documentation and they use pushviewcontroller... try that.